# Macbook Pro: CD Drive to SSD Drive

Tags: virtualization, ssd, macbook-pro

I'm looking to replace my DVD drive on my Unibody MacBook Pro with an SSD drive.

What specs should I look for in buying an SSD (128 gig) for using it to host a Windows 7 VM (VMWare Fusion)

Comment: The Super User Blog has some articles on [how to find the hardware necessary to put an SSD in the optical bay](http://blog.superuser.com/2011/05/04/best-of-both-worlds-putting-an-ssd-in-your-optical-bay/), but shopping recommendations are [off topic](http://superuser.com/faq), so this question needs to be closed. Windows doesn't require any particular SSD, anyhow.

Answer (score 1):

I've got an [OWC Mercury Electra 6G 480](http://eshop.macsales.com/shop/SSD/OWC/Mercury_6G/) as a primary drive and a Western Digital Scorpio Blue 500 in a [OWC data doubler](http://eshop.macsales.com/Search/Search.cfm?Ntk=Primary&Ns=P_Popularity|1&Ne=5000&N=7854&Ntt=data+doubler) inside the dvd cavity for archive data and it works like a champ.

I run 4 to 5 Fusion virtual machines simultaneously and spin up and down another 3 or 4 regularly.  My suspend and restore speeds are down to about 2 seconds on the SSD.  I could never go back.

The big thing to keep in mind is the lack of [TRIM](http://blog.macsales.com/11051-to-trim-or-not-to-trim-owc-has-the-answer) support for non-Apple SSD drives in OS X.

---

**Update: Another data point to consider**

[HardOCP: NAND Flash Faces Off - Synchronous vs. Asynchronous](http://hardocp.com/article/2011/08/07/nand_flash_faces_off_synchronous_vs_asynchronous)

The OWC Electra uses Asynchronous Flash and the OWC Extreme uses Synchronous Flash.  I upgraded from a 3G 240GB Extreme to a 6G 480GB Electra.  I haven't performed any benchmarks but the Electra seems as fast if not faster than the older Extreme even though the HardOCP article would suggest otherwise.